# How to remove a small Polygon from a large polygon? the small polygon is within the large one

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely

I would like to extract a small polygon from a large polygon in order to have a large polygon with a hole in it.

I have a series of polygons in `geopandas` as follows:

```
geomap = import_shapes_list(path_to_data,shapes_folder=,crs='EPSG:4326')
```

The output is :

```
          nom                                           geometry
0  Casablanca  POLYGON Z ((-7.64829 33.50895 0.00000, -7.6483...
```

I also extracted the world coordinates

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

Then selected the country i am interested in

```
WorldGeomap=world[world['name']=='Morocco']
```

The output is:

```
        pop_est continent     name iso_a3  gdp_md_est  \
162  36471769.0    Africa  Morocco    MAR      119700   

                                              geometry  
162  POLYGON ((-2.16991 35.16840, -1.79299 34.52792...
```

How can i extract the polygon of `geomap` from `WorldGeomap`? The idea is to have a big polygon that has a hole in it.

So far, I tried this :

```
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
geomap_world=world[world['name']=='Morocco']

df1=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap.geometry, 'df1':[1]})
df2=gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': geomap_world.geometry, 'df2':[1]})
res_union = df1.overlay(df2, how='symmetric_difference')
res_union
```

but i get an error
`NameError: name 'pygeos' is not defined` eventhough i already installed `pygeos`

```
Collecting pygeos
  Downloading pygeos-0.13-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.4/1.4 MB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in c:\users\badao\desktop\python\venv\lib\site-packages (from pygeos) (1.23.3)
Installing collected packages: pygeos
Successfully installed pygeos-0.13
```

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: can you show us what you've tried? shapely has a pretty good [user guide](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) and creating a polygon is one of the first things in it :)

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look thank you